# How to stop a responsive design from getting wider and wider as you zoom out?

Tags: responsive-design

I'm currently designing my first responsive website and while doing some research I came across 2 sites that seem to have done a good job with it: 1) [www.mashable.com](http://www.mashable.com) 2) [www.bostonglobe.com](http://www.bostonglobe.com).

The main difference between them is that mashable.com has some how made a responsive website that locks the content in place when you zoom out, while bostonglobe.com reacts the same way my design does and just keeps expanding. (I hope this makes sense, if not please press ctrl- on both sites and see the difference)

I'd love to know how mashable did it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is how Mashable does it...

```css
@media (min-width: 640px) { 
.page-container {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    }
}
```